# Understanding Wildcards and Type Inference in Java Generics: Resolving 'Incompatible Types' Error

Tags: java, generics

Can someone explain the concept of using wildcards and type inference with generic types in Java, particularly in the context of the "incompatible types" error I'm encountering when sorting data with a custom method?

```
public class MyClass {

    public static <T> List<T> customSorted(List<? extends T> list, Comparator<? extends T> comparator) {
        List<T> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(list);
        int n = sortedList.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
                T item1 = sortedList.get(j);
                T item2 = sortedList.get(j + 1);

                if (comparator.compare(item1, item2) > 0) {
                    // Swap items if they are out of order
                    sortedList.set(j, item2);
                    sortedList.set(j + 1, item1);
                }
            }
        }
        return sortedList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> numbers = List.of(10, 3, 7, 1, 8, 4, 5, 2, 9, 6);

        Comparator<Integer> descendingOrder = (a, b) -> (int) (a.doubleValue()-b.doubleValue());

        List<Integer> sortedAscending = customSorted(numbers, descendingOrder);
        System.out.println("Ascending Order: " + sortedAscending);

    }
}
```

I am getting compile error in if condition as

Required type: capture of ? extends T    &   Provided T

If it is expecting "? extends T" we can pass T itself or it's subtypes then why I am getting error even after passing T.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 0):

This is why you are getting an *"incompatible types"* error:

Inside your method, when using the *compare* method of the *Comparator*, the compiler can’t be sure that the types of the items in the list and the comparator are compatible, because they could potentially be different subtypes of T.

Now, as a solution, you can change your method signature to use a single type parameter for both the list and the comparator. Something like this:

```
public static <T> List<T> customSorted(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    List<T> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    int n = sortedList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++) {
            T item1 = sortedList.get(j);
            T item2 = sortedList.get(j + 1);

            if (comparator.compare(item1, item2) > 0) {
                // Swap items if they are out of order
                sortedList.set(j, item2);
                sortedList.set(j + 1, item1);
            }
        }
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

With that, the comparator can compare objects of type T or any supertype of T.

Other issue you might want to know about: The comment in your *main* method indicates that you are trying to sort the list in ascending order, but you are actually sorting it in descending order due to the way the comparator is defined.

Good Luck!